# jQuery on not working for dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `.on` on dynamically created elements... Although its not working, and yes I am using a selector :)

```
$(".metadata").on("click", "i.icon-remove", function () {
    console.log("what");
    $(this).parent(".metadata").slideUp(function () { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

This works perfectly for existing content, but not for anything thats dynamically created.  Both initial and dynamic content use the exact same creation method so I know their signatures are the same, any ideas?

Here is my HTML as it stands, the first item is present in the HTML, the second is dynamically created

```
<div class="metadata">
    <input type="text" value="" style="width: 200px;">
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
</div>
<div class="metadata" style="">
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" style="width: 200px;">
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: whether the `metadata` element also is dynamically create

Comment: I've lost count of how many times this question was asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: True, I went through about 5 of them before I posted, however in almost every one the problem was due to a missing selector, not because I hadnt anchored it on a static parent element... Also, does this perhaps not describe a barrier in understanding `on` - I never had a problem before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".metadata i.icon-remove", function () {
    console.log("what");
    $(this).parent(".metadata").slideUp(function () { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Comment: To explain further, event delegation must start with an element that's available on page load. It doesn't have to be `body`, but some available ancestor of your element.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to Pranav's answer, avoid if at all possible doing delegated events off of `$(document)` - that results in **all** events that happen anywhere in the page being inspected for matches to your selector.

Far better would be to use a more targeted selection that exists on the page from the start.  Something like

```
$('#otherDivThatsThere').on("click", "i.icon-remove", function () {
    console.log("what");
    $(this).parent(".metadata").slideUp(function () { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Where, again, `#otherDivThatsThere` is *already* in your dom at the moment that line of code is run.